# Get All Values of Property in Array

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to perform an AJAX request that returns a JSON array that looks similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "message": "test1",
    "expiration": "2017-11-17"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "message": "test2",
    "expiration": "2017-11-17"
  }
]
```

What I want to do is get all of the "message" values. I understand that I could iterate through each object in the array and get the value manually, but what I want to know is if there is a way of getting the values in a one-liner.

The programming language with which I'm most familiar with is VB.NET, and using the same data above, this is basically what I'm wanting to accomplish:

```
Dim messages = (From obj In Array Select p.message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.map` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) as the equivalent of your VB.Net 'select' statement, eg:

```js
var json = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "message": "test1",
    "expiration": "2017-11-17"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "message": "test2",
    "expiration": "2017-11-17"
  }
]

var a = $.map(json, function(e) { return e.message; });
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the map function was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "message": "test1",
    "expiration": "2017-11-17"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "message": "test2",
    "expiration": "2017-11-17"
  }
]

const messageArray = data.map(e => e.message);

console.log(messageArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this;

```
var returnedJsonString="[
{
"id": 1,
"message": "test1",
"expiration": "2017-11-17"
},
{
"id": 2,
"message": "test2",
"expiration": "2017-11-17"
}
]";
var data=JSON.parse(returnedJsonString);//convert json string to object array

var msgs=[];//define an array to store the messages as you retrieve

data.forEach(function(o){
     msgs.push(o.message);
});

alert(msgs.join());
```

Comment: *"I understand that I could iterate through each object in the array and get the value manually, but..."*